# vim temporary disable undo?

Tags: vim, plugins

I followed [add-custom-header-to-your-file](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/vi-and-vim-autocommand-3-steps-to-add-custom-header-to-your-file/) to create my own custom header plugin. When I save the file it will auto. update the current date time to Last-Modified field. But this will add a edit history to undo list. How can I disable the undo temporary ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot disable undo without losing the undo history. Think about the undo implementation; would be pretty hard if you had a gap in there.

If you don't worry about losing the history,

```
:set undolevels=-1
```

(and then restoring to the previous value) will do. Also, `:undojoin` can be used to fuse two otherwise separate entries together. But in your situation, it's probably best to keep the (automated) change inside the undo history.

Comment: thanks @Ingo, could see my comment below? Because stackoverflow's comment not support multi-lines code. So I post answer instead.

Comment: `:undojoin` has other problems; it is not allowed after an undo. I stick to my recommendation of just allowing Vim to keep the automatic modification in its undo history.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to reinvent the wheel. There are a couple of such plugins out there; check out my [AutoAdapt plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4654); the page has links to alternatives.

Comment: thank @Ingo, for now I cannot find better solution. I'm still considering follow your suggestion or just remove the update function. Because still a bit annoying to me. For your AudoAdapt I cannot make it work properly. It will only run the first rule. I don't know is it because I'm using VAM to manage addons. anyways thanks :)~ Hopefully VIM in the further can have better solution. as you mentioned the underlying of undo mechanism difficult to implement to support this. I not really agree. They can just add some function like ignore lines to undo mechanism.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/disable-swap-file-for-large-files Much better answer.

Comment: @Pencilcheck ...for a completely different question, though. The swapfile is unrelated to undo.